# How to filter on multiple fields in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I am creating a site with a search using the query filter in AngularJS. I have found many tutorials on how to implement this search in one field, but none that explain how to search across multiple fields. So if your data has firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" I would like to be able to enter "John Smith" in my search bar, and find the correct results, but only the exact text of "John" or "Smith" works.

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar.html'"></div>
<div class="container" ng-controller="ResListCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Search: <input ng-model="query">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <ul ng-repeat="reservation in reservations | filter:query">
                <li><a href="#">{{reservation.firstName}} {{reservation.lastName}}</a></li>
                <p>{{reservation.resort}}</p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the angular docs it looks like you can pass in an object to the filter. So you could do something like:

```
scope.query = {};
```

Then in your html

```
First name: <input ng-model="query.firstName" />
Last name: <input ng-model="query.lastName" />
```

And your filter expression would remain the same:

```
ng-repeat="reservation in reservations | filter:query"
```

See the details for the 'expression' argument for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make my question clear. I want to be able to search both first and last name in the same search bar. This solution makes two separate search bars.

Comment: You could set up a $watch on that search input, then use split(' ') to get first and last name, and then use the results from that to populate the query.

Answer (score 0):

Filter also accepts a function (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
function(value, index) {
  return value === query.first_name + ' ' + query.last_name;
}
```